# Merge different classes from multiple sources

Tags: c#

I have 2 user objects (both from different data sources)

```
public class UserA 
{
    String Firstname;
    String Lastname;
    String Upn;
    String Id;
}

public class UserB 
{
    String Firstname;
    String Lastname;
    String Upn;
    String MemberOf;
    String SamAccountName
}
```

Now it is possible that user X exists in the both data sources (or maybe just in one of them). In that case the field `upn` would be the same. In theory `firstname` and `lastname`should also be the same. So if only the first one is used that is fine (incase of a difference).

Now i want to merge the objects together so i get a list of unique users. But all the fields of both objects (So i can return this as JSON)

So the final objects (if the user exists in both sources would look like)

```
public class UserC
{
    String Firstname;
    String Lastname;
    String Upn;
    String Id;
    String MemberOf;
    String SamAccountName
}
```

Comment: So, what would happen for `Firstname` and/or `Lastname` fileds if `upn` is same for multiple users. Should they be concatenated? The first one will be used only? Or what?

Comment: @vahdet In theory they should be the same. So if only the first one is used that is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. You can choose what to do with items in one list that aren't in the other list.

Dictionaries are used to increase performance.

```
List<UserA> listA;
List<UserB> listB;

var dictA = listA.ToDictionary(x => x.Upn, x => x);
var dictB = listB.ToDictionary(x => x.Upn, x => x);

foreach(var upn in dictA.Keys.Union(dictB.Keys))
{
   UserC user = new UserC();
   if(dictA.ContainsKey(upn)) //Fill in fields
   if(dictB.ContainsKey(upn)) //Fill in fields     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a unique list from both the objects you need to do it like this. Quick and short.

```
        var uniquelist = (from aa in ListA
                        join ba in ListB on aa.Upn equals ba.Upn into all
                        from avail in all.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        where avail == null
                        select new UserC
                        {
                            Firstname = aa.Firstname,
                            Lastname = aa.Lastname,
                            Upn = aa.Upn,
                        }).ToList();
        uniquelist.AddRange(from ba in ListB
                          select new UserC
                          {
                              Firstname = ba.Firstname,
                              Lastname = ba.Lastname,
                              Upn = ba.Upn,

                          });
```

You can add on your join like this

```
join ba in b on new { aa.Upn, aa.Firstname } equals new { ba.Upn, ba.Firstname } into all
```

And then you can use a json serializer to convert it to `JSON`

Comment: As you use a join (inner join) wont this delete entries that dont match on either side?

Comment: The top statement excludes all matches between the two lists. Include all the differences, and the `AddRange` adds everything that did match. You only have to insert from the one list, because they exist in both lists. the `avail == null` actually makes it a outer join with the `all.DefaultIfEmpty()`

Answer (score 0):

A LINQ Join statement is the best way to merge these two lists, creating a new object from each matching pair.

```
List<UserA> first = ...
List<UserB> second = ...

from a in first
join b in second on a.Upn equals b.Upn
select new UserC 
       { 
         Upn = a.Upn, 
         FirstName = a.FirstName, 
         Id = a.Id, 
         SamAccountName = b.SamAccountName
       }
```

(I've dropped some fields for brevity)

What you can see here is a JOIN statement that takes the first list of users, matches it to the second list of users with the Upn field on both as the key field, and then for each pair of UserA/UserB, creates a new UserC, picking and choosing properties from both entities.

Comment: Does this also take in account non existant entries from either side? as in (left/right) join

Comment: No, it's a very basic inner join.

Comment: How would you approach it to merge matching items on either side but also create those that didnt match?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

- converting the lists to contain the type `UserC`,
- `concat` the lists,
- `groupBy` the concatenated list.

Which would be as follows:

```
var aUsers = new List<UserA>();
var bUsers = new List<UserB>();
// Initialize aUsers and bUsers here

var aUsersAsCUsers = aUsers.Select(a => new UserC{
  Upn = a.Upn, 
  Firstname = a.Firstname, 
  Lastname = a.Lastname,
  Id = a.Id
});

var bUsersAsCUsers = bUsers.Select(b => new UserC{
  Upn = b.Upn, 
  Firstname = b.Firstname, 
  Lastname = b.Lastname,
  MemberOf = b.MemberOf,
  SamAccountName = b.SamAccountName
});

var cUsers = aUsersAsCUsers.Concat(bUsersAsCUsers)
  .GroupBy(u => u.Upn)
  .Select(c => new UserC() 
  { 
    Upn = c.Upn, 
    Firstname = c.Firstname, 
    Lastname = c.Lastname,
    Id = c.Id,
    MemberOf = c.MemberOf,
    SamAccountName = c.SamAccountName
});
```

If `Upn`s are the same, `Firstname` and `Lastname` properties are supposed to be the same also.